# How can i get libreoffice writer to automatically add a closed bracket when I open a bracket?

Tags: libreoffice, writer

I am currently writing my bachelor's thesis in Libreoffice Writer. To make the working process easier I wondered if there is a way to get writer to automatically add an closed bracket when I type an open one. This would be useful, because I have to quote many times and I do this by writing the quote in "..." followed by the last name of the Author e.g. (STEPHEN 2005: 44).
To keep my writing flow going on I would find it easier if I don't have to hop with my fingers so many times to simply write the source of my quote.
So, is there a way to make libreoffice add the second bracket in the moment I enter the first one and then move the cursor back into the brackets so I can continue writing?

Regards, Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up `AutoCorrect Options` in the Tools menu to add in parenthesis.  As a test I set up `ppp` to change to `()`.  However the cursor does not end up inside.

To do this in a single key press, you would need to set up a custom shortcut key (Tools -> Customize, Keyboard tab) to call a macro.  The macro would be pretty simple and could be created by recording it.  This would allow you to move the cursor to end up inside, as you requested.

Instead of maintaining the references manually, for scholarly writing I recommend you use a tool such as [Zotero](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuy-eOnrHJAhUIrD4KHUXJABIQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHhtGcgl9O2ENU90ZLaT3JG7kRo7g&bvm=bv.108194040,d.eWE).  It has a plugin for LibreOffice.  In my experience, maintaining the references manually will eventually lead to mistakes.  Zotero reference stylesheets allow you to use a consistent citation style, something your professors will appreciate.

Comment: I tried the autocorrect option, but as you already said the cursor won't be at te position i would like it to be.
As i already had zotero installed, but have never used it that way, i nevertheless chose that option, since i have absolutely no clue about makros... and Zotero worked wonderfully! Thanks a lot!